# When publisher confirms are enabled, queue length limit is set and overflow is set to reject-publish,why cause in confirm callback I received is null?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am learning Queue Length Limit(https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html), as it says, queue is set to `'x-max-length:10'`,and `'x-overflow:reject-publish'`, and also, I enable `publisher confirms`. So, when the number of messages in the queue reaches 10, the publisher will be informed of the reject via a `basic.nack` message.

And it is: my confirm callback got a false ack, but `cause` is `null`. I'm wondering shouldn't it return something so that I can distinguish this situation. Part of the code is as follows:

```java
  @Bean
  public AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate(@Autowired CachingConnectionFactory amqpConnectionFactory) {
    amqpConnectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);
    amqpConnectionFactory.setPublisherConfirms(true);
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(amqpConnectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback(confirmCallback);
    rabbitTemplate.setReturnCallback(returnCallback);
    return rabbitTemplate;
  }

  static RabbitTemplate.ConfirmCallback confirmCallback = new RabbitTemplate.ConfirmCallback() {
    @Override
    public void confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, boolean ack, String cause) {
      System.out.println(ack);  // when number of messages reach 10, print false
      System.out.println(cause); // when number of messages reach 10, print null
    }
  };

 @Bean
  public Queue queue() {
    return QueueBuilder.durable(DURABLE_QUEUE).withArgument("x-max-length", 10).withArgument("x-overflow", "reject-publish").build();
  }

 @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000L)
  public void produce() {
    Message msg = new Message(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "sth");
    amqpTemplate.convertAndSend("sth", "sth", msg );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the AMQP protocol and Java client provides no information about why a publish failed. Only ack/nack and whether the confirmation is for multiple messages:

```
/**
 * Implement this interface in order to be notified of Confirm events.
 * Acks represent messages handled successfully; Nacks represent
 * messages lost by the broker.  Note, the lost messages could still
 * have been delivered to consumers, but the broker cannot guarantee
 * this.
 * For a lambda-oriented syntax, use {@link ConfirmCallback}.
 */
public interface ConfirmListener {
    void handleAck(long deliveryTag, boolean multiple)
        throws IOException;

    void handleNack(long deliveryTag, boolean multiple)
        throws IOException;
}
```

We added the `cause` because, in some circumstances, the framework synthesizes a nack (for example when a channel is closed while we are waiting for confirmations, where we add `Channel closed by application` as the `cause`.

The framework can't speculate the reason for which we got a nack from the broker.

Answer (score 0):

Spring RabbitMQ does provide information about why a publish failed. Set `spring.rabbitmq.publisher-returns` to `true`.